# GCM to FCM - Where to add Server Key and handling MessageException

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm doing migration according to deprecated of GCM from back end side. 
Adding Admin SDK

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.11.0'
}
```

After that, I do send message as follow

```
String registrationToken = "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN";
// See documentation on defining a message payload.
Message message = Message.builder()
    .putData("score", "850")
    .putData("time", "2:45")
    .setToken(registrationToken)
    .build();

// Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAsync(message);
```

There are 2 questions in here:

**1. How do we set the key here?** 
in GCM, we can do by `new Sender(GCM_key).send(Message)` but I can't find how to set key here. I don't think method setToken is used for setting key.

**2. How do we handle exception here?**
In the library, there's a class named **FirebaseMessageException** extend Exception, so how to handle it?

Any solution will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When using the Admin SDK to send FCM messages, you don't need to set the Server Key anywhere in the request, the Admin SDK as it's named, has an *Administrator-like* privileges when it comes to the Firebase Services, so messages sent using it is automatically authorized.
2. As stated in the [`sendAsync()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging.html#sendAsync(com.google.firebase.messaging.Message)) docs:

> Returns: An [`ApiFuture`](https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/0.2.0/apidocs/com/google/api/core/ApiFuture.html) that will complete with a message ID string when the message has been sent.

From the returned `ApiFuture`, I presume you would just add a listener (i.e. [`addListener()`](https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/0.2.0/apidocs/com/google/api/core/ApiFuture.html#addListener-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.concurrent.Executor-)) or use the [`ApiFutures`](https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/0.2.0/apidocs/index.html?com/google/api/core/ApiFutures.html) util class.